# On AWS during DS record creation I get an error, DS record with DNS name ex.com not permitted in zone ex.com. Why might this be?

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-web-services, dnssec

**Environment:** AWS, DNSSEC

When I attempt to create a DS record to [establish a chain of trust](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/dns-configuring-dnssec-enable-signing.html?icmpid=docs_console_unmapped#dns-configuring-dnssec-chain-of-trust) I get an error that I don't understand.

My full error.

```
Error occurred
Bad request.
(InvalidChangeBatch 400: RRSet of type DS with DNS name example.com. is not permitted in zone example.com.)
```

Oddly enough when I attempt to add the key to a subdomain like *[www.example.com](http://www.example.com)* it works.  But that's not what I need.  I need it to work for the entire domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DS` record for `example.com` would go in the `com` zone as part of the delegation, not in the `example.com` zone itself. This is how the chain of trust is formed, you get the `DS` with a signature from the already validated/trusted parent zone.
(In such an example, it would be managed through your registrar.)

Similarly, if you were to delegate eg `sub.example.com` somewhere else you would have the `DS` (if applicable) in the `example.com` zone as part of the delegation for `sub.example.com`. (Which is why you can add `DS` for other names.)